# combobox showing record linked to previous combobox selection

Tags: mysql, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox that is populated by a column in a MYSQL table.

When an item in this combobox is clicked on it is supposed to show the corresponding record in textboxes.

It doesn't do that. Instead it shows the previous record to the one I selected.

I don't have enough rep to post an images here but if you need a better understanding, here is the image link;

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=be86310

(no adds or popups. just the image)

This is the code

```
    private void Domain_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlcon = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = Avalisque";
        string query = "select * from users.stmp where domain = '" + this.Domain.Text + "' ;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader rdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string semail = rdr.GetInt32("email_ID").ToString();
                string sserver = rdr.GetString("server");
                string sport = rdr.GetString("port");
                string ssecurity = rdr.GetString("security");

                Domain_ID.Text = semail;
                STMP.Text = sserver;
                port.Text = sport;
                security.Text = ssecurity;

            }

            con.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Funny / fustrating part, this code works perfectly in a normal textbox. Type in "Gmail", and gmail setting pop up the moment you finish pressing 'l'...

Any Ideas?

Comment: Question: What happens if you choose AOL and after that Gmail? And fyi: it's smtp.

Comment: Leave it to typo's to make you feel stupid... It shows the Gmail settings. It really doesn't seem to care much for the order. Just which one was chosen before.

Comment: Please let me know if you don't find my answer helpful, so i can rework it if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically: You do not want to do things this way in WPF, use MVVM instead...
If you must, i suggest you get the selected item either from `sender` or even better, the [`AddedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.addeditems.aspx) property of `e` - i have no idea what `this.Domain.Text` points to, but it obviously changes after the event is fired. Though as i said you really want to use MVVM as much as possible when working with WPF, so using the pattern you'd simply have a `CurrentDomain` property and bind the `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` and all the controls displaying the information to it.

Comment: Oh, and i fail to see the point of retrieving this little data from the database synchronously on ui interaction...

Comment: Oh this was of much use actually... I looked up MVVM and according to what I gathered from the article the problem was actually in the xaml. There's a null value set in the combobox. By default its selectedindex = "1" and needs to be changed to "-1" i believe?.. As long as that was there, the first attempt would always return nothing to the cells. Not sure why, haven't finished reading it. Its working fine now.

Comment: Actually this still doesn't explain why you'd get the previous item (even if the first item is empty, there's no reason you shouldn't get the selected one on SelectionChanged).

Comment: Figures... you're right. Just discovered it only works fine when I cut and paste the code into a button. It requires a button prompt to work properly but I guess I can live with that. : /

Comment: Why not just do what i suggested? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Honestly, because I'm new to C# in general. I know what "sender" is, "addeditems" and "e" too. I just don't know how to get them to do what you're suggesting. "MVVM" is a new word to me too. I'm sure I'll get the hang of it soon enough.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `AddedItems`, but should be as simple as calling `string query = "select * from users.stmp where domain = '" + ((ComboBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Content.ToString() + "' ;";` (replacing `this.Domain.Text`), though the MVVM solution is far more elegant...